# How do I find the java float value y that is bigger than the float value x with no representable numbers in-between?

Tags: java, floating-point

For integers, this task is easy.

```
private int x;
private int y
private int checksOut;

public TestCase(int input, int checksOut) {
    if (input == Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("can't increment MAX_VALUE");
    }
    this.x = input;
    this.y = input +1;
    this.checksOut = checksOut;
}

@Test
public void test() {
    boolean biggerThanY = y <= checksOut;
    boolean smallerThanX = x >= checksOut;
    assertTrue(biggerThanY || smallerThanX);
}
```

How can I rewrite this test with primitive floats instead of integers such that I can not find any pair of values for *input* and *checksOut* that do not pass the test?

Comment: `float` doesn't have enough precision for a value in between two large `int` values. You can try `double` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method [java.lang.Math.nextUp(float f)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#nextUp-float-) returns "the floating-point value adjacent to f in the direction of positive infinity."

Answer (score 1):

You use `Math.ulp(float)` (or for `double` use `Math.ulp(double)`)

From the Javadoc:

> Returns the size of an ulp of the argument. An ulp, unit in the last place, of a double value is the positive distance between this floating-point value and the double value next larger in magnitude. Note that for non-NaN x, ulp(-x) == ulp(x).